# John the Ripper --rules option

Tags: passwords, cracking

I am trying to use John the Ripper with custom rules. I first added few extra rules in `/etc/john/john.conf`. For example -

```
[List.Rules:CustomRule]
cA0"[0-9][0-9]"
A0"[0-9][0-9]"
```

Next I tried to generate passwords using those rules but getting extra parameter option

```
$ john --wordlist:short-dict.txt --rules:CustomRule --stdout
Extra parameter for option: "--rules:CustomRule"
```

I am using *john 1.7.8* in *Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS* installed using `apt-get`. Any idea? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with the simple version of JTR (John the Ripper 1.9.0) but it works in "jumbo" edition

I could run something

```
./john -w:mydict --rules=myRules mypasswd
```

So just go here http://www.openwall.com/john/ and download the current version of John the Ripper 1.9.0-jumbo-1 (sources, tar.xz, 23 MB)

An extra tip: I also had a problem compiling it so try to run

> ./configure

separately to

> make

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, current versions of JTR do not support "--rules=something".  There is a mention of this over on the [john-users mailing list](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2011/11/03/2).

So what you will want to do is replace an existing section of the john.conf file with your desired rule set.